# An error while using locks in multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm a beginner learning python and ran into some issues while using locks during multiprocessing.
I get an exit code 0 and the right answer but still have some sort of error message which I really don't fully understand. Here's The code I've written-

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def deposit(balance):
     for i in range(100):
         time.sleep(0.01)
         lck.acquire()
         balance.value += 1
         lck.release()

def withdraw(balance):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        lck.acquire()
        balance.value -= 1
        lck.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    balance = multiprocessing.Value('i', 200)
    lck = multiprocessing.Lock()
    d = multiprocessing.Process(target=deposit, args=(balance,))
    w = multiprocessing.Process(target=withdraw, args=(balance,))
    d.start()
    w.start()
    d.join()
    w.join()
    print(balance.value)
```

and here's the error I get

```
 `Process Process-1:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 
  315, in _bootstrap
  self.run()
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 
  108, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\LearningPython.py", line 10, in deposit
  lck.acquire()
  NameError: name 'lck' is not defined
  Process Process-2:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 
  315, in _bootstrap
  self.run()
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 
  108, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\LearningPython.py", line 17, in withdraw
  lck.acquire()
  NameError: name 'lck' is not defined
  200
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `lck` is out of scope of your child processes. Global variables aren't shared across processes. Try passing the lock into the processes.

Alternatively use threads as suggested in kahn's answer. They are much friendlier and still work fine in this case.

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def deposit(balance,lck):
     for i in range(100):
         time.sleep(0.01)
         lck.acquire()
         balance.value += 1
         lck.release()

def withdraw(balance,lck):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        lck.acquire()
        balance.value -= 1
        lck.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    balance = multiprocessing.Value('i', 200)
    lck = multiprocessing.Lock()
    d = multiprocessing.Process(target=deposit, args=(balance,lck))
    w = multiprocessing.Process(target=withdraw, args=(balance,lck))
    d.start()
    w.start()
    d.join()
    w.join()
    print(balance.value)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Lock is only created in main process and passed to child processes as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

Because `deposit` and `withdraw` run in other processes.In their view,the process is not `__main__`,so the `if` statement is not executed and `lck` is not defined.

Try Run

```
import os
import multiprocessing


def deposit(balance):
    print(os.getpid(),__name__)


def withdraw(balance):
    print(os.getpid(),__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(os.getpid(), __name__)
    balance = multiprocessing.Value('i', 200)
    lck = multiprocessing.Lock()
    d = multiprocessing.Process(target=deposit, args=(balance,))
    w = multiprocessing.Process(target=withdraw, args=(balance,))
    d.start()
    w.start()
    d.join()
    w.join()
```

In my case ,it shows

```
19604 __main__
33320 __mp_main__
45584 __mp_main__
```

Your code can run if you put `lck = multiprocessing.Lock()` outside `if`.But I'm sure it's not what you want.

You should use `threading` instead of `multiprocess` in this case,and have a look at difference between multi-thread and multi-process.

Comment: Placing `lck = multiprocessing.Lock()` outside the `if` would create *different* locks in each process.  Create one lock inside the `if` and pass it as an argument to the other processes so they share the same lock.

Comment: Yes.That's why i said `I'm sure it's not what you want.`.And your way works too. But considering he doesn't seem to be in a situation which needs multiprocessing strongly,I still suggest to use `threading` instead,which don't need to pass `lck` everywhere.

Comment: @MarkTolonen:forget to use at.And in fact he need to pass all shared varible,not only `lck`.

Comment: `threading` is only useful for I/O bound parallelism or calling into other languages that release the GIL (such as via `ctypes`).  The GIL prevents Python-only CPU-bound work from gaining any advantage in threading.  This simplistic example doesn't really gain any speed using either threading or multiprocessing, but it is an exercise in using multiprocessing correctly.

Comment: @MarkTolonen:I believe `threading` is also useful for a simple situation where speed is not the concern.But yes,it could be an exercise in multiprocessing,  or multithreading,or  anything.